# Windows: Problem installing Gurobi, missing distutils module

Tags: python, gurobi, modulenotfounderror

I'm having issues installing Gurobi as the following error keeps coming up.

```
C:\gurobi1003\win64>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gurobi1003\win64\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from distutils.core import setup, Command #, Extension
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

C:\gurobi1003\win64>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am fairly new to programming so please imagine your trying to explain it to a 6 year old. Thanks in advance.

SO I have tried pip installing the distutils package but havent a clue.

Comment: `pip install distutils` is exactly the right solution.  Make sure your pip version matches your Python version.  Which Python do you have?  `python -V` and `pip -V`

Comment: And `pip install gurobipy` will be easier

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the quick reply. Python version 3.12 and pip 23.3

Comment: Python 3.12 is very new, and perhaps gurobi has not caught up.  I might make the radical selection to uninstall it and go back to 3.11.

Comment: @GregGlockner, Thanks that worked for me in the end hopefully wont have anymore hiccups!